# whats wrong with my tracking code?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am trying to set up cross domain tracking and also some other add on's as per the web developer reference guide but its not working.

When I use the google debugger it gives me this error: 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

related to my this line of code: 
ga('create', ‘UA-xxxxx-1', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});

My full code is this:

```js
<script>

(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', ‘UA-xxxxxx-1', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', [‘destination.com']);
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('require', 'ecommerce');
ga('send', 'social', 'socialNetwork', 'socialAction', 'socialTarget', {'page': 'optPagePath'});
ga('send', 'timing', 'timingCategory', 'timingVariable', timingValue, 'optLabel');
ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', 'opt_label', opt_value, {'nonInteraction': 1});
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');  
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

id really appreciate any help as the code is no longer working and I cant track any analytics.

please help.

Comment: Is it because you are using `‘` instead of `'` on `ga('create',...)`?

Comment: Also worth mentioning that in your code block you x'd out the numbers in that line, but in your post above it the numbers are present. Don't know if it is important that those are hidden, but they're there.

Comment: @JCOC611 as well as on `ga('linker')`

Comment: @missy, noted that SO has [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28225390/revisions), if you don't want to disclose your UA code, you'd better generate a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to update this line of code to include your tracking number. I'm seeing this from the snippet you pasted:

```
ga('create', ‘UA-xxxxxx-1', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
```

You should use this instead:

```
ga('create', 'UA-38001765-1', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
```

As well:

`ga('linker:autoLink', ['destination.com']);`

You are using `‘` instead of `'`.

If your code still doesn't work, try going through the troubleshooting checklist: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009683?hl=en. I know I've had issues in the past with other scripts on the page using the same variables as the Google tracking snippet uses.

Comment: in general, this is true. but that is not why he's getting that error.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I will make those 2 changes - I couldn't see them.

Comment: Is there another reason why I am getting this error?

Comment: It looks like you have another similar issue with this line `ga('linker:autoLink', [‘destination.com']);`
Should be `ga('linker:autoLink', ['destination.com']);`

Comment: Hi @CrayonViolent is there another reason why this tracking code will not work? Is it because of the snippets I've included?

Comment: I am going to just focus on the cross domain tracking for now so amending the code as follows, do you think this will work?

Comment: (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxx-1', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
ga('require', 'linker');

ga('linker:autoLink', ['destination.com']);

ga('send', 'pageview');

Comment: @missy there may be other reasons the cross domain tracking doesn't work, but the most immediate reason why, and the exact reason for the error you got, was because of using bad quotes.  If you ARE literally using x's in your account number, then that is an additional issue (which would not actually throw a js error, but you won't see data show up in your report since it's not the real acct#). I personally just assumed you masked it for posting purposes.

Comment: Also, this is a poor quality answer. The user obviously just parroted what people already mentioned to you in comments (I was here, sat here and watched him do it), and then pointed you offsite for more help. In short, this is yet another user just trying to make some easy rep

Comment: @Crayon I'm just trying to help missy find a solution to their problem. I have revised my answer several times to incorporate the ideas of others. What's the problem with that?